# Hammer.js event undefined

Tags: jquery, events, gesture, hammer.js

After updating Hammer to v2 it (maybe not so surprisingly) stopped working. Just can't figure out how I can fix it.

The problem arises at my website which you can visit here: [www.tooi.org](http://tooi.org). If you scroll down to WORK, click one of the projects and then try to click (tap) or swipe. I get the following error in Chrome developer tools:

> **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

This is the code that triggers handleHammer after a gesture:

```
new Hammer(element[0], {
    dragLockToAxis: true,
    dragMinDistance: 0
}).on('tap drag swipe release', handleHammer(event));
```

after this, handleHammer will check every case (gesture):

```
function handleHammer(event) {
    // disable browser scrolling
    event.preventDefault();

    switch(event.type) {
        case 'tap':
            (etc.)
```

and points to hammer.js:2358 where it says the following:

```
2356    var i = 0;
2357    while (i < handlers.length) {
2358        handlers[i](data);
2359        i++;
2360    }
```

I hope somebody can help me :) Thanks

Comment: Are you using hammer jquery plugin..? why `event.gesture.preventDefault();` instead of `event.preventDefault();` ..?

Comment: I don't know, but that fixed error nr.1 :) Now just the second error message remains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass argument as function.

```
new Hammer(element[0], {
    dragLockToAxis: true,
    dragMinDistance: 0
}).on('tap drag swipe release', function(){handleHammer(event)});
```

Comment: Okay nice, the error message doesn't show anymore, but it just skips "case 'tap':" so nothing happens. Is this not supported anymore in Hammer.js v2?

Comment: I opened a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26847219/hammer-js-skips-case-inside-switch