# Hammer.js skips 'case' inside 'switch'

Tags: jquery, case, gesture, hammer.js

After updating Hammer to v2 it doesn't recognize gestures anymore. It does trigger 'switch(event.type)' but skips all of the cases. Is 'case' not supported anymore?

Example of the code:

```
function handleHammer(event) {
    // disable browser scrolling
    event.preventDefault();

    switch(event.type) {
        case 'tap':
            the_single_post.removeClass('grab');
            var tapPos = (event.gesture.center.pageX) - (element.offset().left);

            if (tapPos > paneWidth/2) {
                hammer.next('easeinout');
            }
            else if (tapPos < paneWidth/2) {
                hammer.prev('easeinout');
            }
            break;

        case 'drag':
            (etc.)
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried seeing what it has stored in `event.type` ?

Comment: Okay, the problem was that 'event' wasn't transferred correctly into handleHammer. But after fixing that, it gives me the following error (when tapping):
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined`

Comment: `event.gesture` doesn't exist, it's undefined, what were you expecting to be there in `event.gesture` ?

Comment: Well it worked before, so I expected it would contain `tap` `drag` `swipe` or `release`. Now I know `event.gesture` doesn't exist anymore, but I don't know how to get the same result.. Maybe just use the older version again.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events

Comment: I went back to v1.1.3 and works fine, I'll just leave it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hammer.js 2.0 is rewritten from scratch and works totally different. For example there is no drag event, instead the pan event is supported. You will have to change quite some code to switch to hammer.js 2.0

Comment: Do you have experience with 2.0? Is it worth it to update, performance wise?

Comment: I cannot speak about performance, it was generally quite good for both versions. 2.0 has a little cleaner programming model and probably will, especially in future work, better with modern browser features (like using touch-action). Also 2.0 brings you multi-user multi touch. There are however some drawbacks if your multi-finger gesture touches multiple div's there can be problems.